# "text" is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, deprecation-warning

I am getting ready to update an iOS 6 iPhone app to iOS8. The second line of this code produces an error message ("text" is deprecated. First deprecated in iOS 3.0). The syntax error has been in my app for years not causing a problem but I thought I would clean up any errors before completing my iOS 8 version.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [appDelegate muniClicked:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] text]];
    NSLog(@"cell clicked {%d, %d}}", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `UITableViewCell`? The `text` property has been deprecated since iOS 3.0! The docs tell you what to use in its place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] text]` to get the text displayed in your `UITableViewCell`, try this:

```
[[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text]
```

Reference from the [UITableViewCell documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/textLabel).

Depending on your cell structure, looking at `detailTextLabel` may also be useful, if you're using that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I originally tried your suggestion but left of the extra [ bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as in default `UITableViewCell` there are two `labels` `textLabel`for main text and `detailTextLabel` for detailed text.So you can access the text of `UITableViewCell` by `textLabel.text` for main label

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [appDelegate muniClicked:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel.text]];
    NSLog(@"cell clicked {%d, %d}}", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);

}
```